# Android - convert mp4 to a list of frames programmatically

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, mp4, gif

I want to play some animtaions (actually, gifs) which were previously encoded (with h264 codec) and downloaded from network as mp4 files (because mp4 files are much smaller than corresponding gifs). So, on a device I want to decode mp4 and get all the frames to create animations. And the question - what is the best way to decode mp4 to accomplish my task?